# Infinite recursion when serializing OrientDB RecordID

Tags: java, jackson, orientdb

In my schema I have an abstract class like this:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE)
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id private Object id;
    @Version private Integer version;

    public AbstractEntity() {}

    @JsonProperty // this annotation causes infinite recursion
    public Object getId() { return id; }

}
```

This class is used as superclass for every entity, for example:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE)
public class Usuario extends AbstractEntity {

    private Cadastro cadastro;

    protected Usuario() {}

    public Usuario(Cadastro cadastro) {
        setCadastro(cadastro);
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public Cadastro getCadastro() { return cadastro; }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setCadastro(Cadastro cadastro) { this.cadastro = cadastro; }

}
```

I'm designing a REST layer which will let users create records in db via JSON request/response:

```
@POST
@Path("cadastrar")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response cadastrar(@Context HttpServletRequest request, Cadastro cadastro) {
    OObjectDatabaseTx bd = (OObjectDatabaseTx) request.getAttribute("object.database.tx");

    try {

        bd.begin();
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(cadastro);
        usuario = bd.save(usuario);
        bd.commit();

        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(usuario);
        Response response = Response.status(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED).entity(json).build();

        return response;
        (...)
```

However, in this last method, when I call Jackson to serialize my newly created entity (in `writeValueAsString` method), I get an infinite recursion:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
  com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId["record"]->com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument["identity"]
->com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId["record"]->com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument["identity"]
->com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId["record"]->com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODoc...
```

I can avoid the infinite recursion by removing `@JsonProperty` from `getId` method in `AbstractEntity` class. However, this way the `id` property won't be present in JSON response.

So, how can I serialize the `id` property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Jackson support circular references? Is that the case?

Comment: It has `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to create bidirectional relationships. However, I don't see a circular reference in my case. Also, I don't need to stick with Jackson, if you know another way to easily transform my pojos in json string. Thanks.

Comment: Sure: use the OrientDB API calling .toJSON() of ODocument object bound to the POJO. To get the ODocument object: String json = db.getRecordByUserObject(pojo, false).toJSON();

Comment: I am also dealing with the same problem . is there any kind of idea to solve in python